# Order of execution in async function. How is it determined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

When I run the following [asynchronous](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) code:

```
from asyncio import create_task, sleep, run

async def print_(delay, x):
    print(f'start: {x}')
    await sleep(delay)
    print(f'end: {x}')

async def main():
    slow_task = create_task(print_(2, 'slow task'))
    fast_task = create_task(print_(1, 'fast task'))

    # The order of execution here is strange:
    print(0)
    await slow_task
    print(1)
    await fast_task

run(main())
```

I get an unexpected order of execution:

```
0
start: slow task
start: fast task
end: fast task
end: slow task
1
```

What exactly is happening?

### How can I predict the order of execution?

What I find strange is `print(1)` is ignored until all tasks are finished. To my understanding the code runs as expected until it reaches any `await`. Then it creates a task-loop with any other awaitable it finds down the line. Which it *prioritizes*. Right?

That's what I find surprising. I'd expect it to run `print(1)` before any task is complete. Why doesn't it?

Is that the standard behavior or does it vary? If so, what does it vary upon?

If you could into detail how the event loop works alongside the rest of the code, that'd be great.

Comment: Why would you expect it to do anything else? Both the fast task and the slow task happen at the same time, but you don't `print(1)` until after the slow task is finished.

Comment: (no, really: if we don't know why you expect anything else, I don't know what the misunderstanding that led to this question is, so while I can comment about it, I wouldn't know how to build an actual _answer_)

Comment: ...that said, as a mental model it's best to think about async task scheduling a lot like an OS thread scheduler (even though in reality it's more like a [userland "green thread"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) scheduler from back in the day when that was a thing); where there are some constraints on what the scheduler will do, but it's also generally not something you want to think of as completely deterministic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Could you explain a bit how the event loop works alongside "normal" code in that function? (I edited to clarify)

Comment: `await slow_task` blocks (synchronously!) until `slow_task` is finished. Nothing past `await slow_task` runs until after `slow_task` is done.

Comment: Getting into the details, `await slow_task` passes control to the event loop, and doesn't return the flow of control until the `slow_task` is complete; only after that flow of control is back can `print(1)` be run.

Comment: That said, thank you for the clarification -- it helps me tune my answer.

Comment: (no, `await` doesn't look ahead to see what other `await`s happen later)

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through this:

- You create asynchronous processes for a fast task and a slow task at the same time; even the "fast" one will take a significant amount of time.
- Immediately after creating them, you print `0`, so this becomes your first output.
- You call `await slow_task`, passing control to the event loop until `slow_task` finishes.

  - Because you requested `slow_task`, it's prioritized, so it starts first, so `start: slow_task` is printed.
  - Because `slow_task` contains an `await sleep(2)`, it passes control back to the event loop, which finds `fast_task` as ready to operate and starts it, so `start: fast_task` is printed.
  - Because `fast_task`'s `await sleep(1)` finishes first, `fast_task` completes, and `end: fast_task` is printed. Because we're `await`ing `slow_task`, not `fast_task`, we remain in the event loop.
  - Finally, the slow task finishes, so it prints `end: slow task`. Because this is what we were `await`ing for, control flow is returned to the synchronous process.
- After the slow task has finished, you print `1`, so this becomes your last output.
- Finally, you wait for the fast task to finish; it already did finish earlier, while you were waiting for the fast task, so this returns immediately.

Everything is exactly as one would expect.

---

That said, for the more general case, you can't expect order-of-operations in an async program to be reliably deterministic in real-world cases where you're waiting on I/O operations that can take a variable amount of time.