# How does event loop resolve nested coroutines in asyncio?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

```
async def g(i):
    print("sleeping start", i)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("sleeping end", i)

async def task(i):
    print("start task", i)
    await g(i)
    print("end task", i)

async def f(i):
    print("start", i)
    await task(i)
    print("status update",i)
    print("end", i)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[f(i) for i in range(5)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

I have a series of nested coroutines, with a single entry point that triggers them all with an `asyncio.gather` call.

1. In these kinds of setups, are the outputs deterministic, i.e., we know the order of the prints a-priori to running?
2. When a nested coroutine is called, for ex, when `await g(1)` is called, can the event loop queue that but instead start running `f(2)` instead?

A final follow up, if I do necessarily want the order of outputs to be:

```
start 0
start task 0
sleeping start 0 
sleeping end 0
end task 0
status update 0
end 0
...
```

is there any way to ensure this?

My goal, really, is that when the coroutine containing the task finishes, i.e. `sleeping end i` is reached, it immediately also gets to the `status update i` in the parent coroutine. I ideally do not want a delay or the event loop picking up other tasks between these two events.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022053/order-of-execution-in-async-function-how-is-it-determined

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `time.sleep()` in async function and not `await asyncio.sleep()` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely, yes, I want to simulate a nested coroutine setup with blocking calls. (My use case has both blocking and non blocking calls (i.e. true await I/O operations), but I want to better understand the behavior of task creation/execution).

Comment: @UtsavDutta, Is this something you are expecting ? >>>
start 0
start task 0
sleeping start 0
start 1
start task 1
sleeping start 1
start 2
start task 2
sleeping start 2
start 3
start task 3
sleeping start 3
start 4
start task 4
sleeping start 4
sleeping end 0
status update 0
end task 0
end 0
sleeping end 1
status update 1
end task 1
end 1
sleeping end 2
status update 2
end task 2
end 2..... and so on ?

Comment: Nope, I believe it should be:
`
start 0
start task 0
sleeping start 0 
sleeping end 0
end task 0
status update 0
end 0
`

This is in fact what I observe, and is what I want.
But is it possible to guarantee that when `awaiting g(1)`, the event loop doesn't go off and start running `f(2)` or `f(3)` instead. How can one be sure that it will finish running the "entirety" of the first task, `f(1)`, before proceeding to anything related to `f(2)`, `f(3)`... and so on.

Comment: Did you check the existing answers?

Answer (score 0):

The major change from threading to asynchronous programming, is exactly that *you* tell explicitly where the async loop can switch tasks. So,  if your goals is not to have any task-switching or pause between point "a" and point "b" in your code, it is just a matter of not putting any of `await`, `async for` or `async with` statements between the 2.

So, looking back at your code, in order. First of all: if you ever, at any point use `time.sleep` in async code, you just defeated the purpose of having async code at all: anything that delays in asynchronous **must** be non blocking, either using an `await` expression, or callbacks for low-level stuff. `sleep` is usually used in example code, but that remains valid: even your example won't work better than a sequential program, if you use `time.sleep(...)` instead of `await asyncio.sleep(...)`. In "real" code, the "sleeps" will usually give place to I/O operations of some kind: those *must* be done with a proper asynchronous supporting call that is awaited. for example: `await httpx.get(...)` instead of `requests.get(...)`.

Just renaming the functions to gain some sanity, and calling sleep properly. Also, adding the one needed import statement so that the snippet is a fully stand alone valid example won't hurt anyone. ;-)

```
import asyncio

async def first(i):
    print("sleeping start", i)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("sleeping end", i)

async def second(i):
    print("start task", i)
    await first(i)
    print("end task", i)

async def third(i):
    print("start", i)
    await second(i)
    print("status update",i)
    print("end", i)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[third(i) for i in range(5)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

so;

1. In these kinds of setups, are the outputs deterministic, i.e., we
   know the order of the prints a-priori to running?

It will likely be deterministic - but *you should not* count on it. (yes, laugh ) - because the determinism depends on the "timeout" of asyncio.sleep being exactly the same, and the order of the call. Internally, `asyncio.sleep` use a schema of callbacks to mark the "sleeping task" as done - so the existing implementation should make it so in the order they are created. But any change on the internal implementation details of this would change that. So, even though it **will** print things in ascending order, do not trust that if your problem depends on it. Threat "sleep end" step as undetermined, and just close to time of 2 seconds asked for, when designing your code. Even because, it depends on the async thread being actually free to return to the point where `time.sleep` is being awaited - it will only happen when any other running task reach an `await` expression, and several miliseconds, or even whole seconds, may have passed if there is some blocking code without `await`s.

2. When a nested coroutine is called, for ex, when await first(1) is called, can the event loop queue that but instead start running third(2) instead?

Yes.
Actually, when a co-routine function is called, no code at all is executed. So if I do: `next_step = first(1)` -> there is no `await`, it is a synchronous call, and no other code will be executed when this attribution is done. It is just when I later do `await next_step` (or in your case, when you put a single `await` for the `gather` call), that the event loop will select what runs next, and it might be the body of `third(2)` instead the body of `first(1)`. Although the current implementation *will* run things in order as can be seen in the output printout , that is not in the specs, and should not be trusted upon design.

3. My goal, really, is that when the coroutine containing the task finishes, i.e. sleeping end i is reached, it immediately also gets to the status update i in the parent coroutine. I ideally do not want a delay or the event loop picking up other tasks between these two events.

So, in this code, after `await asyncio.sleep(2)` resolves, there are no other `await`s: the `first` function resolves and returns the program flux to where it is awaited in the `second`, and again, it ends-up running with no further `await`, and the execution continues after the `await` in `third`, and "status update" is printed: no other asynchronous code will run in this mean time.

Now, the output of your code, once we fix the `sleep` call to be async:

```
start 0
start task 0
sleeping start 0
start 1
start task 1
sleeping start 1
start 2
start task 2
sleeping start 2
start 3
start task 3
sleeping start 3
start 4
start task 4
sleeping start 4
sleeping end 0
end task 0
status update 0
end 0
sleeping end 1
end task 1
status update 1
end 1
sleeping end 2
end task 2
status update 2
end 2
sleeping end 3
end task 3
status update 3
end 3
sleeping end 4
end task 4
status update 4
end 4
```

as I said above: although the steps are executed in the order you *wish*, but you can't you rely on that - but you can rely on "sleeping end N", "end task N" and "status update N" is deterministic for any N, with no interrupting code.

Answer (score 0):

Asyncio [somewhere](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L301) calls the tasks' `self.__step` method which runs `coro.send(None)`. It means, the task is only going to give the control back to the event loop when the `coro` finishes or it hits the `yield`. That's the key to answer your questions:

> 1. In these kinds of setups, are the outputs deterministic?

yes it is deterministic "in your case". With this setup, you can call it  hundreds of time and you'll get the same result.

> 2. When a nested coroutine is called, for ex, when `await g(1)` is called, can the event loop queue that but instead start running f(2) instead?

No. It goes to run the body of the `g(1)` coroutine (because it's a coroutine and you `await`ed it) until finishes(as it doesn't have any way to pause - I'm talking about that `yield` which is for example hidden in the `asyncio.sleep()`).

> My goal, really, is that when the coroutine containing the task finishes, i.e.

The "*task*" contains coroutine!

---

Note that in your setup, between `f`, `task`, `g`, only `f` is going to be wrapped inside a Task not the others. So in `coro.send(None)`, that `coro` is `f`.